# Using If statements in Python: If datetime.day == WEDNESDAY then call wed_module()

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, calendar

Okay I want to call a different module for each day of the week in Python. My code right now looks like this:

```
def today_Shift():
    import time
    import datetime
    import calendar
    print "Day of week:", datetime.date.today().strftime("%A")

#This gives me the day of the week. 
#Now I need to know what to compare to what, to determine if for example the day of the       #week is == wednesday. 
#If the day of the week is == Wednesday Then
# call wed_info
#elif:
# call tues_info
#etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `weekday`.  That returns the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

```
weekday = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
if weekday == 4:
  #call wen_module
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have specific functions for each day of the week that do whatever.

```
def wedFunc():
    print "This is for wednesday"

def friFunc():
    print "This is for friday"
```

Then you can make a dictionary that maps the day to the function

```
dayFunctionDict = {"Wednesday" : wedFunc, "Friday" : friFunc}
```

Then you call the appropriate function:

```
>>> dayFunctionDict['Wednesday']()
This is for wednesday
```

Using `datetime`

```
>>> dayFunctionDict[datetime.date.today().strftime("%A")]()
This is for wednesday
```